# Accessing the properties of an object with a string in Swift

Tags: swift

In Javascript I can reference properties of an object like this:

```
obj.prop
```

Or like this:

```
obj["prop"]
```

Is there a similar method in Swift of accessing the properties of an object with a string?

Comment: Only works on certain objects. Is there something more universal?

Comment: No. You need to create NSObject and KVC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do it that would work for any Swift class. However, you can do this:

```
class User: NSObject {
    dynamic var username: String = "admin"
    dynamic var password: String = "123456"
}

let u = User()
u.valueForKey("username") // admin
```

This works if:

- You adopt the `NSObject` protocol;
- You define your `var`s as `dynamic`.